# data structure of json type column has been changed on update

Tags: laravel

I have three json columns:

```
class DeliveryCharge extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'delivery_charges';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    
    protected $casts = [
     "locations" => "json",
     "location_ids" => "json",
     "time_charges" => "json"
    ];
    public $belongsTo = [

        'districts' => [ 'RainLab\Location\Models\District', 'locations->district_id']
    ];
}
```

Save data:

```
$deliveryCharge->location_ids = $data['location_ids'];
$deliveryCharge->locations = Utility::addLocationId($data['location_ids']);
$deliveryCharge->time_charges = $data['charge_time'];
$deliveryCharge->save();
```

Update data:

```
$data = post();
$deliveryCharge =  DeliveryCharge::find($this->param('id'));
$deliveryCharge->location_ids = $data['location_ids'];
$deliveryCharge->locations = Utility::addLocationId($data['location_ids']);
$deliveryCharge->time_charges = $data['charge_time'];
//echo '<pre>';print_r($data); exit;
$deliveryCharge->update();
```

Inspected $data from `save` and `update` function. Both are 100% identical.  But `save` method save data as follows:

```
[{"charge":"80","max_delay":"2","unit":"1"},{"charge":"50","max_delay":"3","unit":"1"}]
```

and `update` method change the data format as follows:

```
{"1":{"charge":"80","max_delay":"2","unit":"1"},"2":{"charge":"50","max_delay":"3","unit":"1"}}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed data was identical but array index was started at 1 instead of 0 in case of `update`. This was the main problem. So I converted the array and set starting index 0.